# Adding Composite Unique key and Duplicate Entry error

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

In a pivot table I need to add composite unique key on two big-int fields.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE KEY `uk_field1_field2` (field1, field2);
```

The query reports error

```
Duplicate entry '24014-1435' for key 'uk_field1_field2'
```

This is the last record in the table with these values I what guess form '24014-1435'. I have confirmed that combination is unique. If I remove that particular record, the error then points to second last row with the same error. Until I flush all the records, I cannot add unique key.

Can I add unique key constraints on table without flushing all rows?

**EDIT**

Table: table_name
Columns:
id  bigint(20) UN AI PK
created_at  timestamp
updated_at  timestamp
applied_at  timestamp
field1  bigint(20)
field2  bigint(20)
field3  bigint(20)
status  varchar(64)

Example Data

```
'2214', '2016-01-05 13:51:03', '2016-01-05 13:51:03', '2016-01-05 13:51:02', '1972', '24', '1155', 'applied'
'2215', '2016-01-05 13:51:05', '2016-01-05 13:51:05', '2016-01-05 13:51:03', '1972', '31', '2137', 'applied'
'2216', '2016-01-05 13:51:06', '2016-01-05 13:51:06', '2016-01-05 13:51:05', '1972', '33', '2487', 'on-hold'
'345', '2016-01-05 08:50:07', '2016-01-05 08:50:07', '2016-01-05 08:50:07', '1717', '54', '4602', 'on-hold'
```

Comment: you have some null value?

Comment: can you provide a small example (table definition and data) that will reproduce your problem?

Comment: @scaisEdge Both of these fields are not nullable here.

Comment: Your example works on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a29f3/3) and MariaDB 10.0.19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THe key echo could be not the key  responsible of the violation ..

> There is no guarantee that the valueaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa-11111 in the
>   message
>
> [23000][1062] Duplicate entry 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa-11111' for key 'mykey'
>
> is the value that actually causes the violation. Seems to be a bug in
>   MariaDB and evtl. in MyS

see this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106294/add-unique-index-fails-with-duplicate-entry-error-but-no-duplicates-found

You can try adding a not unique index and then investigate for the keys with problem  ..

Try investiganting with

```
select field1, field2 count(*) group by  field1, field2
having count(*) >1;
```

Comment: Thanks that was a great help. :)

Comment: Please file a reproducible bug report with mariadb.com

Comment: You, and others, seem to have uncovered a bug in MariaDB.  If one of you can create a small test case that demonstrated, please file a bug report.  This forum cannot fix the problem.  (And I don't think there is a reasonable workaround.)

Comment: @RickJames  i have only suggested a way for solve the problem related to the bugs ... i think the person for the small test is the user who posted the question  .. Shuaid Nawaz